# mysql_fetch_array Returning Two Of Everything

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not exactly new to PHP but I haven't used MySQL that much, so I'll ask you guys about this one.

I have a database with one row of data, which consists of a date and two integers. However, when I query the database with this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM history";
$theQuery = mysql_query($query, $connect);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($theQuery);
```

... and I do a `print_r`, I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2010-08-17
    [date] => 2010-08-17
    [1] => 17454
    [posts] => 17454
    [2] => 1058
    [members] => 1058
)
```

Am I doing something wrong? I plan on having many rows with a ton of data and printing it to a table, THEN how would I go about sorting through it?

Comment: Yes. The wrong thing you are doing is ignoring manual page. Just type in the browser's address bar `php.net/function name` and get every answer to your question: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : You did everything right

You can use **[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)** or `mysql_fetch_array(resource $result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`.

The default is to return `MYSQL_BOTH` (associative array + numeric array).

For more information, see [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to mysql_fetch_array is optional but default is MYSQL_BOTH and will give you values both for indices and keys. You can use MYSQL_ASSOC instead.

The PHP manual on mysql_fetch_array:

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

Answer (score -1):

With mysql_fetch_array, you can run it in a loop ,

ex:

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($theQuery))
{
  echo $array["date"];
  echo $array["posts"];
  echo $array["members"];

}
```